# If the norm of the difference between two unit vector is lower bounded by a positive constant, does it mean that the inner product is upper bounded?

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, triangle-inequality

Let $x,y$ be two vectors with $\lVert x \rVert = \lVert y \rVert =1$ and $\lVert x-y \rVert \geq \delta$, where $\delta \gt 0$. Is it possible to show that, $1-(x^Ty)^2 \geq \delta^2$?

**My Approach:**

$$\begin{align}\lVert x-y \rVert \geq \delta &\implies \lVert x-y \rVert^2 \geq \delta^2 \\&\implies (x-y)^T(x-y) \geq \delta^2 \\&\implies (\lVert x \rVert^2+\lVert y \rVert^2-2x^Ty) \geq \delta^2 \\&\implies 2(1-x^Ty) \geq \delta^2\end{align}$$

I also tried to apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and triangle inequality, but couldn't reach the final statement.